# Non scientific exponent representation using exponent(e) notation in python float

Tags: json, python-3.x

If I have a json file having

```
{ "value": 49.2e-6}
```

If I use json.load() this is converted to

```
{"value" : 4.92e-05}
```

Is it possible to preserve the original value and not change the notation

Comment: The original value *is* preserved. Or are you talking about something other than a floating point value?

Comment: I mean the numeric representation stays as it is stays.The change from 49.2e-6 to 4.92e-05 doesn't take place.Also I don't want to convert them to a string format

Comment: The numeric representation *is* the same. If you are referring to the text of the numeric representation staying the same, you only have two choices: make it into a string, or write your own JSON serializer. Depending on which library your are using, you may be able to provide a custom serializer for just floating point numbers where your code can intuit the desired numeric representation.

Comment: Im using the custom json library.It does have an option to pass float through a custom method but I'm unable to write one which is able to give the output in non scientific representation using the e notation.Any help how to proceed with that ?